# Struct within a struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

How do you access members of a struct that is defined within another struct?
Suppose we have a struct defined as:

```
struct FR {
    size_t n;
    struct FR_1{
        unsigned char r;
        unsigned char g;
        unsigned char b;
    };
};
```

Under visual studio 2015,writing:

```
    struct FR x;
    x.FR_1.
```

does not display options for FR_1 members.On the other hand,writing:

`struct FR_1 y;`
Says: `Error,incomplete type is not allowed.`

How do you deal with this kind of struct?

Comment: You define an inner structure, but no member of that type.

Comment: You need to declare it as **FR::FR_1**

Comment: You know that's covered in every [decent C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1). Maybe you should get one and learn the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The sample declares the type `struct FR_1`, *not a member* of that type. Instead, try:

```
struct FR {
    size_t n;
    struct FR_1 {
        unsigned char r;
        unsigned char g;
        unsigned char b;
    } fr1;
};

FR x;
x.fr1.r = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
struct FR {
    size_t n; // < Declaration of member variable
    struct FR_1{ // < Declaration of nested type
        unsigned char r;
        unsigned char g;
        unsigned char b;
    };
    FR_1 fr1; // < Declaration of member variable
};
```

You need to declare a variable of the type `FR_1` in your `FR` structrure, not only the type itself.

```
FR fr;
fr.fr1.r = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create an instance of the structure. A normal `struct` declaration follows the form

```
struct struct-name {
    members
} inst;
```

So you need to declare it as

```
struct FR {
    size_t n;

    struct FR_1 {
        unsigned char r;
        unsigned char g;
        unsigned char b;
    } fr1;
};
```

Now you can write

```
FR fr;
fr.fr1.r = 255;
. . .
```